# how to write CR/LF line ending into serialport with C or Python?

Tags: python, serial-port, newline, pyserial

I used python and C to communicate with my balance, but I can't write CR/LF line ending into it. why?

```
import serial
bal = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600,timeout=0)
bal.write('P\r\n')
print bal.readline()
```

I can get values through cutecom, but why can't I get values through this code?

I am using Linux, why doesn't the program recognize the line ending?

Comment: What makes you think you haven't written CR/LR onto the serial line?

Comment: I just don't know why it didn't recognize my command? But I can communicate with the balance easily through cutecom. I tried to send "P\r", "P\n", "P\r\n" and "P\n\r" respectively to the balance but none of them was useful. Is it wrong with my command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `timeout=0` and do a `readline()` immediately after sending, the answer is probably not yet received.

Better try `timeout=.5` and adjust the value according to your observations.

In this case, it might as well be that the balance doesn't write correct "lines". In these cases try `bal.read(100)`. The timeout will stop as soon as no further characters are coming.